# How to create multiple QLabels in a gui on PyQt5?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5, self

I've created a gui using PyQt5 in PyCharm and I've managed to get one QLabel with an image in it (Picture1.png) showing up, however, when I try to add a second QLabel with a second image (named Shutter1.png) on the same window, it seems to remove both labels and nothing shows up on the gui. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm a novice! NB I've doublechecked the filepath for both imagePath and imagePath_1 are correct. See below for attached code:

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import pkg_resources


import functions.initialisation as inits
import functions.Sig2Open as S2O
import functions.Sig2Close as S2C

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        self.gui = uic.loadUi('Shuttergui.ui', self)
        # Creates the path of the image
        self.imagePath = "C:/........../Picture1.png"
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gui)
        self.image = QtGui.QImage(self.imagePath)
        self.pixmapImage = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmapImage)
        self.label.resize(self.width(), self.height())
        self.label.move(60, 170)

        self.imagePath = "C:/....../Shutter1.png"
        # Create label that holds the image in imagePath
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gui)
        self.image_1 = QtGui.QImage(self.imagePath)
        self.pixmapImage_1 = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image_1)
        self.label_1.setPixmap(self.pixmapImage_1)
        self.label_1.resize(self.width(), self.height())
        self.label_1.move(60, 170)


        self.gui.showMaximized()


        # redirect closeevent func to main self rather than inside gui
        self.gui.closeEvent = self.closeEvent

        # Initialise shutter functions
        inits.ardopenup(self)
        inits.ardshutup(self)
        self.gui.show()


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        import time
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("main thread quitting")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(pkg_resources.resource_stream(__name__, '/css/darktheme/style.css').read().decode())

    window = Ui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Have a look at [layout management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: `self.label.move(60, 170)` and `self.label_1.move(60, 170)` puts the 2nd label over top of the first.

Comment: Thanks Johnny, although, when I change the .move values, Picture1 still shows up but Shutter1 is nowhere to be seen?

Comment: Is `self.imagePath` the correct path?  Check the value returned by [`self.image_1.isNull()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#isNull).

Comment: So it returns false, implying that it's not a null image. I'm not sure where to go from here...